# Python program to view the same web page a user selected amount of times

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am attempting to open the same desired webpage a selected amount of times (by the user) but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
#Imports modules
import requests
import time

#Assigning variables to strings
import urllib.request

url = "https://r6tab.com/bd6a3f35-5060-499a-8645-369664aae1d9"

# Open the URL as Browser, not as python urllib
how = input("Enter how many views you want!")


for counter in range (0,how):
     page=urllib.request.Request(url,headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
     infile=urllib.request.urlopen(page).read()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/lauchlan/Desktop/sss.py", line 14, in <module>
    for counter in range (0,how):
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
>>>
```

Fixed error but views on the webpage arent counting

Comment: What is the problem you have?

Comment: edited to include error, my bad :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read inputs as integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-integers)

Comment: All `input()` comes in as `str` and you can't use `range()` with `str` at one end

Comment: Hello @xnx!

I've added an answer, does it work for you?

If so kindly remember to upvote and/or choose it as answer :)

Comment: It looks like you know how to accept answers here, @xnx. Although it is not mandatory to accept answers, if someone reminds you about it, remember that they took the time to help you. Some things are just good to do, even if they are not obligations `:-)`.

Answer (score 1):

`input` returns a string. You need to convert to an integer to use it in `range`. Try:
`how = int(input("Enter how many views you want!"))`

Comment: I got that and got rid of the error but the views on the page arent counting

Comment: How are you expecting the number of views to go up? Do you have some kind of view counter on the page?

Comment: yes it counts the page visits on the page, so if i enter 1000 i expect it to go up by 1000

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code, I think it is very straight-forward:

```
import requests

url = "https://r6tab.com/bd6a3f35-5060-499a-8645-369664aae1d9"
how = int(input("Enter how many views you want: "))
headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

for counter in range (0,how):
     print "Counter value:\n" + str(counter)
     response = requests.get(url)
     print "Response status:\n" + str(response.status_code)
     page = response.text
     print "Response text:\n" + response.text
```

Keep in mind that your counter could be intelligent enough to stop counting visits from the same IP in a short period of time.